# jad does not always work for classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, decompiling, decompiler

I have set `Jad` for eclipse. I am able to decompile the java source code so I assume that the configuration is setup properly.

The problem is that some jars I include seem not to be decompiled. I.e. when I press on the class name that has been introduced from one of my jars I don't see the source but the class file editor complaining that the "Source not found".

Why could this be happening?
If I am able to view the java source code, doesn't that mean that decompiler has been properly setup?

Comment: What do you mean by "set Jad for eclipse"? By Jad are you referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29)?

Comment: @Celeritas:Yes.http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page. I thought this is what everyone is using

Comment: This is a bit more than just Jad and Eclipse, it's a plugin that integrates the two programs together. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @Celeritas:But if I am able to view the java source code, doesn't that mean that decompiler has been properly setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Wikipedia page pointed at by Celeritas: "*The most recent version of JAD says it supports only Java class file versions 45.3, 46.0 and 47.0, not ones produced by Java 5.*"
We can suppose you are trying to open modern class files...

You might want to install [JD | Java Decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) instead. It has an Eclipse plug-in of its own (which I use), but it seems that JadEclipse also supports it. JD supports up to Java 7 bytecode format.

[EDIT] Currently JD-Eclipse has hosting problems, the plugin being flagged as virus by the host...

You can install it the old way, ie. by downloading the zip file (jdeclipse_update_site.zip) and dropping the **features** and **plugins** folders in the Eclipse installation folder... Don't forget to set the **Class File Editor** (the name of the JD editor) to ***.class** and ***class without source** in Preferences > General > Editors > File associations and set it as default.

Comment: How can I know the file version of a class?

Comment: I get this `An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,jd.ide.eclipse,0.1.3.` trying to install your recommended plugin

Comment: Yes, it looks like the author is currently having problems with his hosting of the Eclipse update files (the file is marked as virus by the host!). I update my answers with some instructions for manual install.

Comment: The hosting problems are solved. You can use the "JD-Eclipse Update Site" or download "jdeclipse_update_site.zip". If you download the archive, do not copy folders "features" and "plugins" yourself. Click on "Help > Install New Software... > Add... > Archive...".

Comment: @EmmanuelDupuy, I still get `An error occurred while collecting items` this way.